# AVAudioSession Buffer Duration on iphone6* Simulator

Tags: buffer, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession

I'm setting a preferred buffer duration of `0.0001` seconds using `AVAudioSession` and not getting logical results using the simulators.

```
   [session setPreferredIOBufferDuration:self.bufferDuration error:&audioSessionError];
   if (audioSessionError) {
      NSLog(@"Error %ld, %@",
            (long)audioSessionError.code, audioSessionError.localizedDescription);
   }
```

The problem is that in my `Audio Unit` render callbacks, I always get `512` frames to process as the `inNumberFrames` argument.

On my device, setting the preferred buffer duration results in different buffer rates.  For example, if I set `self.bufferDuration` and then set the `AVAudioSession` with `0.1`, than I will get `4096` sized `inNumberFrames`  arguments to my render callbacks.  On the simulator, it will be 512.

I wanted to check if this is normal behavior (i know many things don't work identically on the simulator and device), or if this is a problem with my assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the setPreferredIOBufferDuration setting is just a preference suggestion not a hard setting.  The OS is free at run-time to choose a number of frames (duration of actual data times the sample rate) to send to audio callbacks, and to even change that number while an app is running audio in the foreground.  The actual duration may vary between different iOS devices and Mac systems.  The duration might also depend the sample rate or format, the audio route, whether there are any other background app audio sessions that are currently active, the audio settings used by the immediately prior app, and/or on the OSX or iOS version and version of iOS Simulator.

For a requested buffer duration of 0.0053, I seem to get 512 frames on the iOS 9.2 Simulator, and 256 frames on an iPhone 6s (only the latter matching the request, but this will **not** be true at all common sample rates).  Some older iOS devices will not return a frame count below 256.

It is invalid to assume that inNumberFrames will correspond to an app's preferred buffer duration setting.

Comment: My question was specifically about this behavior of getting `512` frame sized callbacks on the simulator and if that is normal behavior.  I've read the entire `AVAudioSession` programming guide and so I'm aware of those different runtime behaviors and how the setting is simply a request.  (although that request should be deterministically honored in the absence of those specified edge cases, no?).

Comment: What is interesting is that using the `CoreAudio` function `AudioUnitGetProperty()` with `kAudioUnitProperty_MaximumFramesPerSlice` returns `4096` frames even though the buffer rate reverts to `512` frames at runtime.  (I call this getter after the `remoteIO` unit is started).  The problem is I have Visual display code that shows waveforms and whose scale is determined by the actual frame sizes at runtime.  So on the simulator it expects `4096` and indeed that is what `AudioUnitGetProperty()` returns, but the sound data only has `512` frames so I see waveforms only covering ~1/8 the screen.

Comment: The proper technique is to use a lock-free circular buffer so that the Ui display code waveform size and audio callback buffer length are completely decoupled and independent.  I use that technique in my iOS apps to change the waveform view length and FFT length over a very wide range without depending on or varying the audio buffer duration.

Comment: Perhaps "edge cases" connotes the wrong thing.  What I meant was outside of the given reasons (app goes into background mode, etc...), the preferred duration will result in some staircase-stepped preset frame sizes.. (e.g. 256,512,1024... I've even gotten as low as 14 frames on my iphone 6+!).

Comment: However, there is still the problem of `AudioUnitGetProperty` returning `4096` frames although the runtime frame size winds up as `512` frames.  I'm not sure of another way to request the buffer size in frames at run time besides that Core Audio function.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the Circular FIFO.  Its been a while now that I've been putting off learning how to implement and/or incorporate one, but I suppose now is the time.

Comment: You can't request a guaranteed number of frames under iOS.  Even the number 256 isn't guaranteed on new devices (which is why a whole bunch of audio apps had to be updated for the iPhone 6s Plus.  All the developers who assumed a constant 256 frames were wrong and thus had to fix their bug.)

Comment: Does anyone have a link to official documentation stating the facts about the ever changeable number of frames in a recording callback?